# How can I fix this Jittering in my IK rig?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I'm having a Jittering problem with my IK rig for a robot arm. I have included video and my .blend file. The Jittering occurs even when I remove the constraints. The only time it does not happen is when I remove the IK. What did I do wrong?

https://youtu.be/oTAyQ5HnbP4
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SuX5tKYR5SSA04ZfR0qmZAuf-t1AkX-t/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bone called *IteratorArm.IK*, which is supposed to be the IK controller, is parented to the IK bone called *IteratorArm.001*, which creates a circular dependency, deparent it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This completely fixed the problem!